# Fetch multiple mysql rows at once in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

How can I fetch multiple rows at once from a MySQL table in PHP?

Suppose my query returns 5 rows in all and I specify a block size of 2, the function must return an object/array with 2+2+1 rows successively.

P.S. I know that I can iterate over all the results manually and do the same implementation myself, but I am looking for some built-in function that does this cleanly and in an optimized way.

Comment: What is your db driver: MySQLi, PDO?

Comment: I am not exactly sure. I use the built in PHP function mysql_fetch_row to do this. What driver is this?

Comment: @Gowtham That's a function belonging to the mysql extension. Those functions are no longer recommended.

Comment: I just read that these functions are deprecated. Is there a way to do this using any other driver?

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions as they are in the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead and [be a better PHP Developer](http://jason.pureconcepts.net/2012/08/better-php-developer/).

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the tip. Noted for future use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're looking for does not exist. Write it yourself.

Comment: I have to accept this as the right answer. Will change it if anyone comes up with something better.

Answer (score 1):

Look into using the [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) object if you're not already using it. That way, you'll be able to make use of the [fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php) function.

```
<?php
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT name, colour FROM fruit");
$sth->execute();

/* Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set */
print("Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:\n");
$result = $sth->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
?>
```

Fetch all of the remaining rows in the result set:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => pear
            [0] => pear
            [COLOUR] => green
            [1] => green
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [NAME] => watermelon
            [0] => watermelon
            [COLOUR] => pink
            [1] => pink
        )

)
```

Comment: +1 for providing code, but this does not solve my problem. It fetches all the rows at once and I have to iterate over them again individually. I want a bunch of rows to be fetched at once.